# Got django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "currency_id" violates not-null constraint Error When i give post request from postman-DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have got not null constraint error when I give post request,

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from hrm_apps.common.models import CurrencyMaster
class Currency(models.Model):
    currency = models.OneToOneField(CurrencyMaster, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    conversion_rate = models.FloatField(null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

serializers.py

```
class CurrencySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    currency = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='currency.name')

    class Meta:
        model = Currency
        fields = ["id", "currency", "conversion_rate"]


class MasterSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CurrencyMaster
        fields = ('id', 'code', 'name')
```

views.py

```
class CurrencyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Currency.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CurrencySerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'
```

Any help Appreciated..

Comment: What Django version are you using? Do you actually have a field called 'currency_id' on your CurrencyMaster model? Can you please share the model?

Comment: I am using django version 3.2.8


class CurrencyMaster(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name